# How to create a lambda procedures?

Tags: scheme, anonymous-function

I need to complete an assignment for my college course using Scheme. I've never coded in Scheme before so I have no clue what I'm doing. Our assignment is to define an anonymous function that computes the discriminant of a quadratic function. I keep running into the error: "Invalid `define'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(define roots (lambda(abc))(
  (lambda(discriminant))(
    list(/(+(-b) discriminant)(*2a))
        (/(-(-b) discriminant)(*2a))
  )
        (sqrt - (*bb)(*4ac))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn a bit about what Scheme code looks like; find some example code (in your textbook, or online, or in answers here on SO) and notice how parentheses and whitespace are used. Then emulate that. You can't arbitrarily place parentheses or arbitrarily remove whitespace in Scheme (or in any Lisp).

For example, in the posted code `(-b)` gets two things wrong. First, `-b` is treated as *one symbol*, not as the negation of the value of `b`. Further, placing the symbol in parentheses indicates a procedure call; given an s-expression `(f x)`, `f` is either a syntactic keyword (in which case `(f x)` is interpreted as a macro call), or `(f x)` is interpreted as a procedure call. If it is a procedure call and `f` is not bound to a procedure, then an exception is raised. So `(-b)` attempts to call a procedure named `-b`, which does not exist (unless you have defined it), raising an exception. You can use `(- b)`, with a space between the `-` procedure and the symbol `b`; this evaluates to the negation of the value of `b`.

Similarly, `*2a` is interpreted as a *symbol*, not an expression; placing the `*2a` between parentheses is interpreted as a procedure call. The interpreter (or compiler) is expecting that `*2a` is a procedure which takes no arguments. You need to add the spaces: `(* 2 a)`; this is interpreted as a call to the procedure `*` with the arguments `2` and `a`.

`(*bb)` and `(*4ac)` have exactly the same problems. The second case is interesting because when it is correctly written it illustrates one of the advantages of prefix notation. Since `*` is associative, it does not matter what order multiple values are multiplied in. To express naively `4 * a * c` in prefix notation you could write `(* 4 (* a c))`, explicitly ordering the multiplications. You could also write this as `(* (* 4 a) c)`, multiplying in a different order. It does not matter what order you multiply in, so you might as well just write `(* 4 a c)`, so long as your language supports this notation. It turns out that Scheme and other Lisps do support this notation.

Another problem with s-expression notation in the posted code (after fixing the problems noted above): `(sqrt - (* b b) (* 4 a c))`. This is attempting to call the `sqrt` procedure on the arguments `-`, `(* b b)`, and `(* 4 a c)`. But `sqrt` is not a higher-order procedure (i.e., it does not take procedures as arguments), and it in fact only takes one argument. It was meant to apply the `-` procedure to the arguments `(* b b)` and `(* 4 a c)`, subtracting them before taking the square root: `(sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))`.

The first `lambda` expression has a formal parameter list containing only one parameter: `abc`. As before, this is a mistake. The intention was to define three parameters: don't skimp on spaces: `(lambda (a b c))`.

The other significant problem is that there are syntax errors in the `lambda` expressions: `(lambda (a b c))` has no body, but a `lambda` expression *must* have at least one expression in its body. This was probably intended to wrap the `lambda` expression which follows. Similarly, the inner `lambda` expression is missing its body. It was probably intended to wrap the `(list ;;...)` form that follows.

With that done, the inner `lambda` expression is itself inside of a pair of parentheses, taking the expression `(sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))` as its argument. This is the `lambda` form of a `let` binding. Thus, the inner `lambda` takes one argument, `discriminant`, and evaluates the `list` form that is its body. Since the inner `lambda` expression itself occurs in the first position of an s-expression, it is part of a procedure call, and this inner anonymous procedure is then called on its argument, binding `discriminant` to the value obtained by evaluating that argument, which is `(sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))`. This all occurs inside of the outer `lambda`, which takes the three arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`. So, `root` is a function taking three arguments, and returning a list of roots, after binding the result of the discriminant calculation to `discriminant` (as a way of both simplifying the expression of the roots and ensuring that the discriminant need only be calculated one time).

Here is the fixed-up code. Note that I only added some spaces and added or moved a few parentheses; nothing else was changed:

```
(define roots
  (lambda (a b c)
    ((lambda (discriminant)
       (list (/ (+ (- b) discriminant) (* 2 a))
             (/ (- (- b) discriminant) (* 2 a))))
     (sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c))))))
```

Pay attention to what this looks like. In Lisps you should almost never leave parentheses hanging on lines by themselves, and you should always place a space between arguments. Remember that everything is a procedure call.

Here is a sample interaction. Notice that you *can* represent negative numbers as `-1` instead of `(- 1)` (you can do either if you wish). You just can't express a negative value using a variable as `-b`.

```
> (roots 1 0 -1)
(1 -1)
> (roots 1 8 15)
(-3 -5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything in depth! I've been struggling trying to figure it out. Definitely have a lot to learn about the language but this helped a lot. Thanks again